# Adding UserControl from one window to the MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a Mainwindow and a groupbox inside it.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" 
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="600" Width="800">

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <GroupBox Header="Diagram Design" Name="gbDiagDesign">    
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

A simple UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Controls.EntityControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btn_show" Content="show me" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and another window with an OK button in it, 
the question is how do I add the UserControl to the Groupbox in the MainWindow after I press the OK button.

```
 public partial class NewEntity 
    {

        public NewEntity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EntityControl entcon = new EntityControl();
            **MainWindow.gbDiagDesign.Children.Add(**
        }
```

the last row gives me an error, "an object reference is required for the nonstatic field.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `MainWindow` using `Application.Current.MainWindow` but it will return instance of `Window` class. `Typecasting` is required to convert it to actual class instance i.e. MainWindow.

This should work:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).gbDiagDesign.Add(entcon);
```

Comment: working! thank you very much.. is it wrong to do that in this way? what is the correct way to add controls to the mainwindow?

Comment: Its not wrong but you are doing it in traditional way of WinForms. You should read more about Binding and MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is meant to be programmed using the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern. If you do it another way, you will have to fight WPF all along instead of using it's great power. If you insist on doing it the other way, at least make the compiler happy:

MainWindow is a instance variable of your application class. You are not inside your application class, so you need an instance of your application class first to access MainWindow. You will also need to cast it to your Window type.